# How to write multiple dataframes into multiple sheets in a memory and time efficient way in python?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a list of `Dataframe` which I need to write to in excel file in different sheets. Currently I am using the below code -

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
sheets = ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet4']
df_sheets = zip(dfs, sheets)

for df, sheet_name in df_sheets:
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace')
    writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)
    writer.close()
```

Now this is taking much more time and memory. I have tried to move the `writer` initation before loop and `writer.close()` after loop. But then nothing gets written to excel file.

Comment: It's always going to be slow if you open the workbook for each dataframe.

Comment: @CharlieClark oh that means I should move the everythin apart from `df.to_excel(...)` before loop. and `writer.close()` after loop?

Answer (score 0):

Moving `writer` stuff before loop makes it fast.

```
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
sheets = ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet4']
df_sheets = zip(dfs, sheets)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a', if_sheet_exists='replace')
writer.book = openpyxl.load_workbook('output.xlsx')
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in writer.book.worksheets)
for df, sheet_name in df_sheets:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)

writer.close()
```

Comment: This is as per the pandas docs.